# NullPointerException: onTouchEvent() HERE Maps Android SDK

Tags: android, here-api

My crash reporting system has reported a number of `NullPointerExceptions` which appear to be related to the HERE Maps Android SDK. It doesn't give me any specific line number from my code so I'm unsure how to debug and fix the issue. I've not been able to replicate it on my own device. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)' on a null object reference
com.here.android.mpa.internal.bs.onTouchEvent(MapViewImpl.java:300)
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent (View.java:10717)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2859)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2535)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2865)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2492)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2865)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2492)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2865)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2492)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2865)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2492)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2865)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2492)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2865)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2492)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2865)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2492)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:559)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1870)
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent (Activity.java:3236)
android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:521)
android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:10946)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5110)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:4962)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4493)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4546)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4512)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4645)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4520)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4702)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4493)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4546)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4512)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4520)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4493)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7000)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:6929)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6890)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7110)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent (InputEventReceiver.java:185)
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: This bug will be fixed in the upcoming release.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you contact HERE map support. This is a bug inside the code of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered your same problem before. My problem is no error before android5.0 system will hang after android6.0. After the application is detected android6.0 permission is dynamic, I added the dynamic application permissions in the code after the problem is solved. Don't know if this solution is useful to you?